# Manga where the main character was the captain of a knight squad, but died and was reincarnated as a noble lady or princess in the same world

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character is the captain of a knight squad, a male, died and was reincarnated as a noble lady or princess (sorry I forgot) in the same world.

I think he died because of war. One of his/her squad members, the youngest if I remembered it right, and now a captain also, is falling in love with him/her.

Comment: Are there any other details you can remember? For example, were there any floating islands in the story? Or was the (reincarnated) protagonist's mother a skilled warrior?

Comment: They're not an Elf girl, right? https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/all?include_tags=208,317,314&page=1 has just a bit more than 1 page of results... https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/saikyou-kenshi-no-restart-light-novel is Great Swordsman reincarnates into a pre-teen elf princess-y...

Comment: Figured out how to exclude Light Novels from the search. Is now only has 19 options. https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/all?include_tags=208,317,314&exclude_tags=334 ... Found this which is Gender Bending + Manga, but can't trim more: https://anilist.co/search/manga?format=MANGA&genres=Gender%20Bending

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[This Girl is a Little Wild](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/this-girl-is-a-little-wild)*?

> As he was being defeated, the Demon King used the last of his strength
> to curse Sir Roel, the legendary captain of the Holy Knights, into the
> body of a weak girl. Roel — who was a woman to begin with! — tired of
> her former life and unable to return to her original body, decides to
> live a luxurious life as Sila Epheria, the noble daughter whose soul
> got swapped with hers. Things don't go according to plan when her new
> family puts her in danger, forcing her to find a way to prove her true
> identity... Will Roel/Sila be able to live a quiet life as she wishes?
> Or is there something more to the new life she's received?

[image]

Comment: What I'm looking for is a manga not manhwa. And the main character was a male. If I remember right, this manhwa s mc was a male-looking female knight captain. So its not...

Comment: @リッカ - The main character of this one was ambiguously female.

Comment: You also might want to edit into the question your certainty that it was manga.

Answer (score 0):

From a knight to a lady? I believe that might be the manwha you're looking for not quite sure though. Cuz I was looking for this one and this is the closest thing and I think this is exactly what I was looking for so hopefully it helps you as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Isn't that a webtoon?  The question says it's looking for a manga.  Can you explain more how it matches the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Saikyou no Kurokishi, Sentou Maid ni Tenshoku shimashita

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/saikyou-no-kurokishi-sentou-maid-ni-tenshoku-shimashita - close, but not a noble lady. instead is now a maid.